# How do I know if a web page has opened in Jenkins?

Tags: powershell, jenkins, automation, automated-tests

I want to set up Jenkins to interact with a web application and return results, but first I'm testing it out on webpage.

I simply want to interact with Random.org, to press a button to return a value, but I can't even seem to open the webpage itself.

I've tried the following code:

```
#Start-Process 
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application

$ie.Navigate("https://www.random.org")
$ie.visible = $true
sleep 30

if( $ie.visible -eq $true)
    {
echo "Random.org opened"
   }
else
{
echo "Random.org did not open"
}
```

But this always returns the echo `"Random.org did not open"`. I've realized now maybe `$ie.visible -eq $true` is not the best method to check with jenkins, as it is running in the background and cannot be seen. is there another way I can check to see if the webpage is opened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just query the `busy` property of your `InternetExplorer.Application` COM object:

```
#Start-Process 
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application

$ie.Navigate("https://www.random.org")
while( $ie.busy){Start-Sleep 1}
```